# How to resize image with fixed width and height while uploading

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

When I upload an image I want to compressed with fixed width and height, I have tried lot. I have attached my coding below:

```
$extension = getExtension($filename);
                    $extension = strtolower($extension);


                    if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
                    {
                    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpFilePath);
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                    $src = imagecreatefromgif($tmpFilePath);
                    }
                    list($width,$height)=getimagesize($tmpFilePath);


                    $newwidth=1000;
                    $newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
                    $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);


                    $newwidth1=540;
                    $newheight1=236;
                    $tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1,$newheight1);

                    $newwidth2=253;
                    $newheight2=($height/$width)*$newwidth2;
                    $tmp2=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth2,$newheight2);

                    $newwidth3=840;
                    $newheight3=365;
                    $tmp3=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth3,$newheight3);

                    imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

                    imagecopyresampled($tmp1,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);

                    imagecopyresampled($tmp2,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth2,$newheight2,$width,$height);

                    imagecopyresampled($tmp3,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth3,$newheight3,$width,$height);


                    $filename = "gallery/".$_FILES['egallery_img'.$i]['name'];

                    $filename1 = "gallery/ms". $_FILES['egallery_img'.$i]['name'];

                    $filename2 = "gallery/vs". $_FILES['egallery_img'.$i]['name'];

                    $filename3 = "gallery/medium". $_FILES['egallery_img'.$i]['name'];



                    imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);

                    imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100);

                    imagejpeg($tmp2,$filename2,100);

                    imagejpeg($tmp3,$filename3,100);

                    imagedestroy($src);
                    imagedestroy($tmp);
                    imagedestroy($tmp1);
                    imagedestroy($tmp2);

                    imagedestroy($tmp3);

                   $epaname = $filename;
                   unlink($deletImg);
                   unlink($msdeletImg);
                   unlink($vsdeletImg);
                   unlink($mdeletImg);
```

I am getting the width as it is given in my coding, but I am not getting the correct height.

How can I solve this? or is there anyone who can suggest me some other way to solve this. If I fixed the width and height it means my image is getting damage. Once again thank you.

Comment: If you're asking a question about PHP, please don't tag HTML, CSS and jQuery. You haven't included the PHP tag, so not many PHP developers will help you. I will change this for you.

Comment: Ya thank you brother, i will correct myself.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend SimpleImage class, it is very simple to use.

Example of use:

```
$img = new SimpleImage('source/path/of/your/image.jpg');

// Resize the image to 320x200
$img->resize(320, 200);

$img->save('destination/path/for/new-image.jpg');
```

You can get it from https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage